# closedness and compactness of semisimple subgroups of compact groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group. Then by Levi-Malciv $G=S\cdot Z$ where $Z$ is the connected component of the center and $S$ is the maximal semisimple subgroup.

How to show that $S$ is connected, closed and compact subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Levi-Malcev says that $S$ is a maximal *connected* semisimple subgroup. So $S$ is connected. Also $S$ is compact since closed subgroups of compact Lie groups are again compact.

Comment: Thanks. But why it is closed?

Comment: A compact Lie group is a real linear algebraic group. Since linear algebraic groups in characteristic zero have a Levi decomposition, $S$ is a closed linear algebraic subgroup.